# Download files to a specific location using Postman

Tags: download, postman, autodesk-forge

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/download-file/#step-6-download-the-item

I have followed the tutorial and have successfully obtained the contents of the file, but where is the file being downloaded. In addition, how do I specify the location of where I want to download the file?

Result on Postman
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of `Send`, hit the downward arrow immediately on the right and select `Send and Download` in the dropdown. Then once the response comes back you will be prompted with where to save the download:

[image]

Comment: How to give the location through Test or scripts in Postman ?